# ImmediateDeprecationError when using data reader

Tags: python, datareader, stock, pandas-datareader

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import style
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
style.use('ggplot')
start = dt.datetime(2000,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2016,12,31)

df = web.DataReader('INPX', 'yahoo', start, end) 


ImmediateDeprecationError                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-d0b9e16fb581> in <module>()
----> 1 df = web.DataReader('INPX', 'yahoo', start, end)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, access_key)
289     """
290     if data_source == "yahoo":
--> 291         raise ImmediateDeprecationError(DEP_ERROR_MSG.format('Yahoo Daily'))
292         return YahooDailyReader(symbols=name, start=start, end=end,
293                                 adjust_price=False, chunksize=25,

ImmediateDeprecationError: 
Yahoo Daily has been immediately deprecated due to large breaks in the API without the
introduction of a stable replacement. Pull Requests to re-enable these data
connectors are welcome.

See https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues
```

I tried the link but I couldn't find the reason why there is an immediate depreciation error. I also tried changing 'yahoo' to 'google' ie:df = web.DataReader('INPX', 'google', start, end) but there is still an error:

```
/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/google/daily.py:40: UnstableAPIWarning: 
The Google Finance API has not been stable since late 2017. Requests seem
to fail at random. Failure is especially common when bulk downloading.
```

warnings.warn(UNSTABLE_WARNING, UnstableAPIWarning)

```
RemoteDataError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-5d16a3e9b68a> in <module>()
----> 1 df = web.DataReader('INPX', 'google', start, end)

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/data.py in DataReader(name, data_source, start, end, retry_count, pause, session, access_key)
313                                  chunksize=25,
314                                  retry_count=retry_count, pause=pause,
--> 315                                  session=session).read()
316 
317     elif data_source == "iex":

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py in read(self)
204         if isinstance(self.symbols, (compat.string_types, int)):
205             df = self._read_one_data(self.url,
--> 206                                      params=self._get_params(self.symbols))
207         # Or multiple symbols, (e.g., ['GOOG', 'AAPL', 'MSFT'])
208         elif isinstance(self.symbols, DataFrame):

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py in _read_one_data(self, url, params)
 82         """ read one data from specified URL """
 83         if self._format == 'string':
---> 84             out = self._read_url_as_StringIO(url, params=params)
 85         elif self._format == 'json':
 86             out = self._get_response(url, params=params).json()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py in _read_url_as_StringIO(self, url, params)
 93         Open url (and retry)
 94         """
---> 95         response = self._get_response(url, params=params)
 96         text = self._sanitize_response(response)
 97         out = StringIO()

/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas_datareader/base.py in _get_response(self, url, params, headers)
153             msg += '\nResponse Text:\n{0}'.format(last_response_text)
154 
--> 155         raise RemoteDataError(msg)
156 
157     def _get_crumb(self, *args):

RemoteDataError: Unable to read URL: https://finance.google.com/finance/historical?q=INPX&startdate=Jan+01%2C+2000&enddate=Dec+31%2C+2016&output=csv
Response Text:
```

b'Sorry... body { font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif; background-color: #fff; color: #000; }**Google**Sorry...

## We\'re sorry...

... but your computer or network may be sending automated queries. To protect our users, we can\'t process your request right now.

See [Google Help](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640) for more information.
[Google Home](https://www.google.com)'.

Thankyou so much for helping!

Answer (score 3):

A small change as discussed [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/487) worked for me. Just use

```
import pandas_datareader.data as web
sp500 = web.get_data_yahoo('SPY', start=start, end=end)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error is self-explanatory; the Yahoo API has changed, so the old Pandas code to read from Yahoo's API no longer works. Have you read [this discussion](https://github.com/pydata/pandas-datareader/issues/487) about the API change and its impact on Pandas? Essentially, Pandas can't read the new Yahoo API, and it will take a long time to write new code, so the temporary solution is to raise an `ImmediateDeprecationError` every time someone tries to use Pandas for the Yahoo API.

Answer (score 0):

it is obvious that the api `get_data_yahoo`, goes wrong.
Here is my solution:

- First, install fix_yahoo_finance:

  ```
  pip install fix_yahoo_finance --upgrade --no-cache-dir
  ```
- next, before you use the api, insert the code:

  ```
  import fix_yahoo_finance as yf
  yf.pdr_override()
  ```

Best wishes!